# Testing for Dictionary KeyNotFoundException

Tags: c#

I have a scenario where there is a dictionary that might or might not have a key value at a given time. I am presently testing to see if the value exists in the following manner, but would like to know if this is the best approach or if there is a better approach for handling this.

```
int myInt;

try
{
    myInt = {Value From Dictionary};
}
catch
{
    myInt = 0;
}
```

Any input? Thanks.

Comment: `if(dict.ContainsValue(value))` or check key `dict.ContainsKey(value)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the dictionary's [TryGetValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method

```
  int myInt;
  if (!_myDictionary.TryGetValue(key, out myInt))
  {
      myInt = 0;
  }
```

A couple of people have suggested using ContainsKey. This is not a good idea if you actually want the value because it will mean 2 lookups - e.g.

```
if (_myDictionary.ContainsKey(key)) // look up 1
{
 myInt = _myDictionary[key]; // look up 2
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example for you

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
 static void Main()
 {
  Dictionary<string, string> test = new Dictionary<string, string>();
  test.Add("one", "value");
//
// Use TryGetValue to avoid KeyNotFoundException.
//
string value;
if (test.TryGetValue("two", out value))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Found");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Not found");
}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, using `try catch` is not a good idea here, you are unnecessarily slowing down the code where you can easily accomplish that with `ContainsKey` or `TryGetValue`

I would propose the solution with `TryGetValue` as mentioned here - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw5aaea4(v=vs.110).aspx (check the examples)

But you can optimize more. The line `myInt = 0;` is redundant as @Mark suggested. `TyGetValue` automatically puts the `default` value ( `0` for `int`) when it returns.

> If the key is not found, then the value parameter gets the appropriate default value for the type TValue; for example, 0 (zero) for integer types, false for Boolean types, and null for reference types.
>   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

So the final code could be

```
int myInt;
if (_myDictionary.TryGetValue(key, out myInt))
{
    [...] //codes that uses the value
}else{
    [...] //codes that does not use the value
}
```

Or -

```
int myInt;
_myDictionary.TryGetValue(key, out myInt))
[...] //other codes.
```

The next paragraph is copied from the documentation ot **TryGetValue**-

> This method combines the functionality of the ContainsKey method and
>   the Item property. If the key is not found, then the value parameter
>   gets the appropriate default value for the type TValue; for example, 0
>   (zero) for integer types, false for Boolean types, and null for
>   reference types. Use the TryGetValue method if your code frequently
>   attempts to access keys that are not in the dictionary. **Using this
>   method is more efficient than catching the KeyNotFoundException thrown
>   by the Item property.** This method approaches an O(1) operation.

**BTW**, `ContainsKey` and `TryGetValue` both has running time **O(1)**. So, it does not matter much, you can use any.

Comment: ContainsKey and TryGetValue both have running time ~ O(1). but if you use the former and then use the indexer to get your value then you have 2 x O(n). So, as I said in my answer, *if* you are going to use the value, TryGetValue is the preferable method.

Comment: TryGetValue does not perform any magic to get the values. It uses both the options as said - "This method combines the functionality of the ContainsKey method and the Item property". You are implicitly using both.

BTW, it is not 2 x O(n), it is O(2n) ~ O(n), where n = 1

Comment: "Functionality" does not imply equivalence.  In reality, `TryGetValue` uses a try/catch around the indexer.  So, only one lookup.  Check reflector.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the generic dictionary, then the best way to avoid the exception is to use the ContainsKey method to test if the dictionary has a key before using it.

Comment: If you're going to pull the value regardless, `TryGetValue` makes more sense.